# Slide DIV's from left or right using buttons and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm trying to create a function that can slide div's from left or right based on what step you are in the process.

This is my basic structure:

```
<button type="submit" id="button1">Go to Step 1</button>
<button type="submit" id="button2">Go to Step 2</button>
<button type="submit" id="button3">Go to Step 3</button>

<div id="container">

    <div id="div1">Text 1</div>
    <div id="div2">Text 2</div>
    <div id="div3">Text 3</div>

</div>
```

Using jQuery I have this, but it's **not** what I want:

```
$('#div1').animate({'width': 0}, 500,function(){ // Slides DIV to left
    $('#div1').css('display','none');
    $('#div1').css('width', 1100); // Set the correct with on DIV again
    $('#div2').fadeIn('slow'); // Fade in new DIV
});
```

What I'm after is when I'm in Step 1 and press button two (Go to Step 2) I want div2 to slide in from the right (inside the container-div). When I'm in Step 3 and press button one (Go to Step 1) I want div1 to slide in from the left (inside the container-div) without seeing div2 on the way over. I'we looked at different jQuery sliders but they all handle pictures.

Here is an example that does something along the lines what I what to achieve but does not have the left/right slide functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/2uV2h/ (source: [How to Slide div's off/on page using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549523/how-to-slide-divs-off-on-page-using-jquery)). Please ask questions if something is unclear :) Thanks in advanced.

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/t5qnw5v5/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nkwinder already posted an answer with a jQuery plugin, but I went ahead and cut jQuery completely out of the question, I don't know if you prefer that, but if you want that solution, it is here https://jsfiddle.net/3ydpa3oL/ , I may have even modified your jsfiddle, no idea how does that page work.

What I did:

I put another element inside of #container, so that it contains all of the .boxes and named it #slider.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="slider"> <!-- NEW ELEMENT NEEDED  -->
    <div id="div1" class="boxes">Text 1</div>
    <div id="div2" class="boxes">Text 2</div>
    <div id="div3" class="boxes">Text 3</div>
  </div>
</div>

.boxes 
{
  width: 50px; // CAUSE I DID NOT WANT TO MESS AROUND TOO MUCH
  height: 20px; // CAUSE I DID NOT WANT TO MESS AROUND TOO MUCH
  font-size: 1em; // CAUSE I DID NOT WANT TO MESS AROUND TOO MUCH
  float: left; // SO THAT THEY SLIDE LEFT AND RIGHT
}

#container
{
  width: 50px; // WINDOW EFFECT
  height: 20px; // WINDOW EFFECT
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden; // WINDOW EFFECT
}

#slider
{
  position: relative; 
  width: 200px; // ENCLOSE .boxes
  transition: left 1s; // NO JQUERY
}

#div1 {
  background-color: green;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

All of the .boxes HAVE TO be always visible, and the container HAS TO have an overflow property set to hidden, so that everything outside of its size is clipped. #slider is there to make float:left work, otherwise the .boxes the size of #container and do not behave very well.

Now it is easy to have a nice animation on the divs with a simple transition property on #slider, because we just move this element around and because #container clips everything outside of it, we get a nice effect of sliding .boxes.

Bare in mind that this approach forces you to write some additional code ( not provided by me ) to adjust the size of #slider, otherwise float:left is not going to behave correctly and the .boxes will appear on top of each other, which will ruin the effect. You could probably use display:flex to fix that, if you can use CSS3 freely.

Comment: ...and thanks for explaining how the solution works.
The slide efffect does not work on the first push of a button. Also, when I am in div3 and press to go to div1 I do not want to see div2 on the way over. I did not mention this in my question, sorry - I will update my quesiton.

Comment: Ye, sorry about that, I was being quick about the reply, as I answer from work. It does not work on the first click, because the element does not have a "left" css attribute yet assigned, it does not even exist, that's why it first needs to be created. The solution to this is to either init the slider element with slider.style.left = "0px"; or add style="left: 0px;" to slider div.

Comment: @David The other problem is very easy to solve as well, again, sorry I did not include it, but You could have done it yourself, really. Well, maybe not THAT easy, because you have to deal with a lot of nonsense, you obviously need to use display:none; on all of the elements that are between your target and your current selected element, but when you do that, everything will move out of position, so you would have to create a class that "watches" and makes all of these changes, so that you can manage everything accordingly, easy, but way too much work. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/non-image.php
You can slide div's not only images. You don't have to implement sliding with custom code.